# Regex to match exact path with two /

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match below path with a regex.

```
# test-site could be anything like "shoe-site", "best-clock", etc.
/content/test-site
```

The current regex rule `(\/content\/{1}\S+)` would have been adequate.

The problem is it is matching the entire path such as `/content/test-site/en_US/abc.html`.

I need it to match only `/content/test-site`.

Example of path to be matched:

```
https://localhost:4502/content/test-site/en_US/book/city/sample-rooms/airport-inn/propertyCode.00000.html
```

Regex I've tried by far;

```
(\/content\/[a-z-]+)\/[a-z]{2}_[A-Z]{2}\/book(ing-path)?\/(sample-|sample-details)(.*).[0-9]{5}.*

/content/test-site is optional- it might not present sometimes in url.
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: If "test-site" always consists of two words (alphanumeric or underscore) separated by `-`, you may use `\/content\/\w+-\w+`. See it here: https://regex101.com/r/vjx05U/1. If it can be anything except `/`, then you may use `\/content\/[^/]+`. Please note that `{1}` is redundant.

Comment: Just replace `\S+` with `[^\/]+`

Comment: Mach for character repetition. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023902/it-is-possible-to-match-a-character-repetition-with-regex-how

Comment: soo... are you matching against a full URL, or just the path? Because your "path to be matched" example is a full URL...

Comment: @CrayonViolent just the path - not full url. some times it would have /content/test-site, some times not. /en_US/... etc.

Answer (score 1):

Regex to match any character expect `/`:

```
content\/[^\/]+
```

This is character classes. A character class beginning with caret will match anything not in the class. More [about this.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

So, with javascript:

```js
const url = '/content/test-site/en_US/abc.html';

const path = url.match(/content\/[^\/]+/)

console.log(path[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach:

```
(?:\/[a-zA-Z0-9-]+){2}
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jSuMcB/1)

Explanation:

```
(?:                 # Non-capturing group
\/[a-zA-Z0-9-]+     # Match starting with / and followed with characters/digits/-
)                   # Close grouping
{2}                 # Match two times, i.e. only match with two /
```

Comment: Why did you assume that "content" isn't a constant?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed in the question it doesn't mention anywhere that content is a constant. What if it is not? We don't know, I'm leaving this for OP to decide. My answer is just one of possible approaches.

Comment: The OP used it as a constant (i.e., in his/her pattern). I wouldn't _assume_ otherwise, but maybe that's just me :)

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I see your point, I don't think my answer does any harm though, if OP confirms that it is a constant I will delete answer, no problem.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed thanks for the response. can you tell me ?: why this is needed ? thanks.

Comment: @Sri this is a non-capturing group, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions

Comment: /content/test-site is optional , in above regex it is saying +, I am not sure if I could do a whole group zero or one time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use negated character class

```
^(?:[^\/]*\/){2}[^\/]*
```

[image]

```js
const path = '/content/test-site/en_US/abc.html';

const desired = path.match(/^(?:[^\/]*\/){2}[^\/]*/)

console.log(desired[0])
```