# How to capture same letters with regex?

Tags: regex

How can I capture words of the from `**` where `*` is some letter of the English alphabet, but I don't want words like `ab`, only words where the two letters are the same, e.g. `aa`, `bb`, ...

What would be a suitable regex expression that captures words of that form?

`(aa|bb|cc|dd|...)` would obviously work  but doesn't seem very concise.

Comment: I think this should help, but is not the same as your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023902/it-is-possible-to-match-a-character-repetition-with-regex-how

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What regex can match sequences of the same character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644714/what-regex-can-match-sequences-of-the-same-character)

Answer (score 0):

If your words consist only of letters you can use backreference this way:

```
(.)\1
```

Here, `(.)` captures any character, while the backreference `\1` recollects the previously captured character and looks to match any immediate repetitions of it

Comment: Surely `([a-z])` or `([a-zA-Z])`, rather than `(.)`.